# method return unexpected error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a textarea to display the HTML content from the database. Here my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  $('#cont').html('<?php echo $cont['0']['desc'];?>');
  $('#name').html('<?php echo $cont['0']['name'];?>');
  //]]>    
</script>

<textarea name="cont" id="cont"></textarea>
<textarea name="name" id="cont"></textarea>
```

When I try to load content dynamically, `#name` is working perfectly but the `#cont`
shows an console error like:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

This is the content I am attempting to load in to the `#cont`

```
<h3 style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: kozgopro-medium; font-weight: 500; line-height: 1.1; color: #014d7e; margin: 0px; font-size: 24px; padding: 5px 0px;">Coconut Oil</h3>
<h5 style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: kozgopro-medium; font-weight: 500; line-height: 1.1; color: #0091f0; margin: 0px; font-size: 16px; padding: 10px 0px 5px;">Extra Virgin / Premium</h5>
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: An ID should be unique, You should never have 2 x `id="cont"`

Comment: What does the content of the `script` tag look like after being populated by the PHP?

Comment: Aside from duplicate `id` attributes, the error implies that the value you're echoing from the PHP contains an `'` character which is breaking the string delimiters. You need to escape that character in PHP

Comment: thank you Anderson and Rory, i using unique id. i found the problem is inside of my html it have a " or ' it was created this kind of problem how to overcome from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.`id` need to be unique per element

2.You can use `name` attribute as selector also

***So code needs to be:-***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('textarea[name=cont]').html('<?php echo addslashes($cont['0']['desc']);?>'); 
  $('textarea[name=name]').html('<?php echo addslashes($cont['0']['name']);?>');
</script>

<textarea name="cont"></textarea>
<textarea name="name"></textarea>
```

***Hardcoded Working snippet:-***

```js
$('textarea[name=cont]').html('hey how are you?');
$('textarea[name=name]').html('I am fine Man!');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="cont"></textarea>
<textarea name="name"></textarea>
```

Comment: try like this:- `$('textarea[name=cont]').html('<?php echo addslashes($cont['0']['desc']);?>');
 $('textarea[name=name]').html('<?php echo addslashes($cont['0']['name']);?>');
`